# Disable NetBios over TCP/IP & also get Location id for a NIC using powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, nic

I wanted someone to help me out to disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP and also to get the location ID of a NIC using PowerShell,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First thing** : Here is a way to disable Netbios over TCP/IP

```
# My network card name
$networkCardName = "Connexion au réseau local"
$adapter=(gwmi -query "select * from win32_networkadapter where netconnectionid= 'Connexion au réseau local'").deviceid
([wmi]"\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Index=$adapter").SetTcpipNetbios(2)
```

With different values available for '`SetTcpipNetbios`' :

0 (0x0) Enable Netbios via DHCP

1 (0x1) Enable Netbios

2 (0x2) Disable Netbios

**Second thing** : The location ID for a NIC what do you mean ?

Comment: hi @JPBlanc with location id i meant was going into a network card properties --> click on configure --> click on details --> select the property as location information -->  get the value

Comment: You mean for example 'Bus PCI 0, périphérique 25, fonction 0'